# tap/click view action Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

is there a `Touch Up Inside` for views?
I want to call an action when the user tap's or click's a view.
Currently I use a hidden button over this view, but thats not a smart way.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: add a Gesture recognizer. probable tap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you can also use the addGestureRecognizer method on UIView like so:

```
// In some View controller
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR;
tapGR = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];
tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myUIView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

// Add a delegate method to handle the tap and do something with it.
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why using the hidden button would be not a smart way ... It is the suggested way by Apple itself, i think it is smart and the better way at the moment ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` if you are looking to detect touches anywhere on the screen with no buttons. You can also find the location of the touch like so:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint *tLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Note: `touchesEnded` is called **EVERY SINGLE TIME** the view is tapped, so the above `tLocation` will change every time the user touches the screen.